# Converting text into json object using python

Tags: json, python-3.x, text

I am new to python , and i want to convert a text file with following sample data to a json format ,
here is a sample data:

> User
>
> Name: John
>
> Office: 1st Ave
>
> Birth date: 1978-01-01
>
> User
>
> Name: Jane
>
> Office: 2nd Ave
>
> Birth date: 1970-01-01

I want to create a JSON object that looks like:

> [ {"Name " : "John","Office":"1st Ave", "Birth date": "1978-01-01"}, {"Name":"Jane","Office": "2nd Ave","Birth date": "1970-01-01"}]

This is just sample data , i want to do it for a very large data , how can i do it.

**EDIT:**

tried this :

`details= ["Name","Office","Birth date"]`

`details_data = ["John", "1st Ave", "1978-01-01"]`

`data = dict(zip(details, details_data)`

`json.dump(data, file)`

The above code works fine , but how can I make the complete data into a json format?

**EDIT 2:**

An issue i am facing now is that , with a limited set of data i.e some 1000-2000 lines its working but when i am trying to convert a very large file say some 20000-30000 then it only converting the same first 1000-2000 lines.

Any idea on why it is happening and how can it be resolved?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? Give a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the file isn't in a standard format that i'm aware of you're going to have to iterate over it and make the rows yourself.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json

data = []
row_data = None
with open("example.txt") as example:
        for row in example:
                row = row.strip()
                if not row: # ignore newlines
                        continue

                if row == "User": # We have a new row and the last one is finished
                        if row_data:
                                data.append(row_data)
                        row_data = {}
                        continue

                key, value = row.split(": ")
                row_data[key] = value

data.append(row_data) # The last row is determined by the EOF not "User"

with open("example.json", "w") as jsonfile:
        json.dump(data, jsonfile)

with open("example.json") as jsonfile:
        print(json.load(jsonfile))
```

Result:

```
[{'Name': 'John', 'Office': '1st Ave', 'Birth date': '1978-01-01'}, {'Name': 'Jane', 'Office': '2nd Ave', 'Birth date': '1970-01-01'}]
```

An explanation of what's happening:

Create a new list `data` that will house our rows. Set `row_data` to `None` which will be used in our checks later..

We strip each row (this might not be necessary, but it seems like it couldn't hurt).

If the row is `""` we'll skip it, to ignore all those redundant newlines.

If the row is "User" that means we have a new row to build. It also means we should append the last row if we have one. This will happen twice with the example text you gave. We initialize an empty dict.

For every other row we just split on ": " to get our key and value, we add that key and value to our `row_data` until we encounter another "User" line.

We do this once more after we've looped through the file to get the last row. Since we won't have the "User" check to rely on to append that row.

We open the json and dump as you've already been doing.. I open it to print it out for the sake of this example.